# Django and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, dotcloud

I am running a website on dotcloud which uses nginx to serve both static content and html pages, and django to serve json for ajax requests.

I am having trouble configuring my nginx.conf file, since it seems that anything not specifically mentioned here will be given to django which will produce an error.

For example, say a user wants to access the "about" page, so they type www.example.com/about into the browser. I want nginx to server back about.html without django being involved at all. How can I do this? I've tried the following:

```
rewrite ^/about/?$  /path/to/file/about.html break;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Am i doing something wrong here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question probably belongs here http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the preferred way but you could use:

```
location /robots.txt { alias /home/www/static/any-filename.txt; }
```

To serve single file.  Found in [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) and on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/278351/nginx-root-versus-alias-for-serving-single-files)

Comment: so say someone requests www.example.com. Can I say location /r { alias /home/www/static/home.html; } and have it work?